# Testing Tracer spring sleuth

Tags: spring, mocking

I want to write for a Tracer spring sleuth test. I have some testing difficulties. I have such code and test below. But I get error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.TraceContext$Builder.build()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.TraceContext$Builder.traceId(String)" is null
How to fix it or how to write correctly unit test

```
public void sendSingleEmailToGateway(String systemName, SendEmailsToGatewayRequest.Emails.Email email, Long finalMessageId, String traceId, boolean isRetryMessage) {
    try (Tracer.SpanInScope span = tracer.withSpan(tracer.spanBuilder().setParent(tracer.traceContextBuilder()
            .traceId(traceId)
            .build()).start())) {
        try {
            validateAndSendEmail(systemName, email, finalMessageId);
        } catch (WebClientResponseException e) {
            processErrorMessage(systemName, email, isRetryMessage, finalMessageId, traceId, e);
        }
    }
}

and unit test 
 @Test
    void send_email_valid_request_from_rabbit_with_valid_configs() {
        Span.Builder spanBuilder = mock(Span.Builder.class);
        TraceContext.Builder traceContextBuilder = mock(TraceContext.Builder.class);

        when(emailMessageService.saveAndGetMessageIdFromDb(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(MESSAGE_ID_FROM_DB);
        when(getMailingsConfigsRepository.isValidMessage(anyString(), anyString(), any())).thenReturn(true);

        when(tracer.currentSpan()).thenReturn(span);
        when(span.context()).thenReturn(traceContext);
        when(tracer.nextSpan()).thenReturn(span);
        when(traceContext.traceId()).thenReturn("15245");
        when(traceContext.spanId()).thenReturn("12");

        when(tracer.spanBuilder()).thenReturn(spanBuilder);
        when(tracer.traceContextBuilder()).thenReturn(traceContextBuilder);

        when(tracer.traceContextBuilder()).thenReturn(traceContextBuilder.traceId("445455")
        .spanId("455454"));


        emailSender.sendEmailFromRabbit(SYSTEM_NAME, VALID_REQUEST, MESSAGE_ID_FROM_RABBIT);

        verify(emailGateOperationClientApi).sendEmailsToGateway(responseCaptor.capture(), messageIdCaptor.capture());
    }
```